# Homework Assignment, Function Totally Differentiable, Correct Solution?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We are given the following function:

\begin{align*}
  f: \mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
  f(x,y) &=
  \begin{cases}
  {x^3y^4 \over x^6 + y^4} \ & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
  0 \ &(x,y) = (0,0)
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

and should argue why it is totally differentiable in $x^0 = (0,0)$. Using the defintion of total differentiable, my argument goes:

J(f, (x,y)) = $
  ({{\partial \over \partial x}f(x,y)}, {{\partial \over \partial y}f(x,y)}) =
  ({3x^2y^8 - 3x^8y^4 \over (x^6 + y^4)^2}, {4x^9y^3\over (x^6 + y^4)^2})$

a function is totally differentiable if:

\begin{align*}
 \lim_{x \rightarrow x^0}{f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x^0}) - J(f, \mathbf{x^0})(\mathbf{x-x^0}) \over ||\mathbf{x - x^0}||} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}
\end{align*}

Since:

\begin{align*}
 f(\mathbf{x}) &=  {x^3y^4 \over x^6 + y^4} \\
 f(\mathbf{x^0}) &= f((0,0)^T) = 0 \\
 J(f, \mathbf{x^0}) &= (0,0) \\
\end{align*}

thus:

\begin{align*}
 \lim_{x \rightarrow x^0}{f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x^0}) - J(f, \mathbf{x^0})(\mathbf{x-x^0}) \over ||\mathbf{x - x^0}||} = \lim_{x \rightarrow x^0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{||\mathbf{x}||} = \frac{0}{0} = 0
\end{align*}

Comment: $\frac 0 0=0$?...

Comment: year right. that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments there is a problem in your last limit since $\frac{0}{0} = 0$ as no meaning.

The partial derivates at $(0,0)$ are

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f((h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{0}{h^6}- 0}{h } = 0$$

and $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0,h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0.$$

We now investigate the limit as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ of 
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \frac{\frac{x^3y^4}{x^6 + y^4} - (0,0)\cdot (x,y)}{\Vert(x,y)\Vert} \right\vert &= \left\vert\frac{x^3y^4}{(x^6+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right\vert\\ &= \left\vert \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \frac{y^4}{x^6+y^4} \right\vert  \\ &\leq  \left\vert\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right\vert \\  &\leq\frac{r^3}{r} = r^2 \to 0
\end{align*}
where we used polar coordinates. Therefore $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0).$

Comment: x = rcos(phi); y = rsin(phi) => (rcos(phi))^3 / sqrt(r^2(cos^2(phi) + sin^2(phi))) = r^3cos^3(phi) / r; cos^3(phi) <= 1; => r^3cos^3(phi) / r <= r^2. Are those the steps in between? Makes a lot of sense. Thx so much.